# System of equations Find the value of $k$.

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

for what value of $k \in \mathbb{R}$ does there exist exactly one pair $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfies the simultaneous equations

$$y-14x=k$$
$$x^2 +y = 5$$

Comment: Where do $(x,y)$ live ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

$$y-14x=k$$
$$x^2+y=5$$
By the former,
$$y=14x+k$$
Substitute it into the latter,
$$x^2+14x+(k-5)=0$$
As you want the value of $x$ to be unique, then the discriminant 
$$\Delta=14^2-4k+20=216-4k$$
Must be $0$.

Thus,
$$4k=216$$
$$k=54$$

Answer (score 0):

from the first equation we get
$$y=14x+k$$ plugging this in the second equation we get
$$x^2+14x+k-5=0$$
solving this we get
$$x_{1,2}=-7\pm \sqrt{54-k}$$
we get only one solution if $$k=54$$

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate $y$ from the second equation giving
$$x^2+14x+k=5.$$
Completing the square
$$(x+7)^2=54-k.$$
For which $k$ has this quadratic repeated roots?

Comment: If you vote to close a question as off topic, unclear, a duplicate, etc., Why would you answer it.  It is precisely questions which are off-topic, unclear, duplicate, etc that ought to be "hands off" for answering.  FYI, whatever... You see, answering a question, while also voting to close, can very understandably be attributed to an attitued, on your part such as  "now that I've answered, the question we should close it, so no more folks can answer it.  I can answer such a question, but no one else should be allowed to."